# need to scrape links from a list of websites . But cant use the code on more then one. What can I do?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-extraction

```
from http.client import responses
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

url =  'https://10minuteschool.com/skills'

http = httplib2.Http()

responses, content = http.request(url)

links = []

for link in BeautifulSoup(content).find_all('a', href=True, target=True, rel=True):
    links.append(link['href'])


for link in links:
    print(link)
```

Comment: What do you mean that you can't use the code on more than one?

Comment: yes 
i want to use it on a list of urls all at once .

and im not able to do that .

Comment: how can i use the code on a list of url at the same time ?

Answer (score 2):

I have run your code and it completes with the following result:
[image]

If that is the only issue then you just need to pass `features="lxml"` to the BS constructor, as the error states, so

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(content).find_all('a', href=True, target=True, rel=True):
```

becomes:

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(content,features="lxml").find_all('a', href=True, target=True, rel=True,):
```

and then you end up with a clean result:
[image]

Comment: but i still cant use it on more then 1 url and i want to use it on a list of urls what can i do ?

Comment: @fahim_faisal What happens when you run the code. Post a screenshot or an error or something. Do you mean that you want the code - that gets a list of links from a webpage - you would like to run against multiple urls and get the links on each of them, adding them all to the list together, then printing each?

Answer (score 0):

To utilize the same [or very similar] code to target multiple URLs we can just run the code that works for 1 URL `for` each URL in a `list` of URLs instead of just a single string.

```
from http.client import responses
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

#url =  'https://10minuteschool.com/skills'

urls = ['https://10minuteschool.com/skills','https://10minuteschool.com/skills','https://10minuteschool.com/skills']

http = httplib2.Http()
links = []

for url in urls:
    responses, content = http.request(url)    

    for link in BeautifulSoup(content,features="lxml").find_all('a', href=True, target=True, rel=True,):
        links.append(link['href'])

for link in links:
    print(link)
```